# Dependency issues while installing ns2

Tags: software-installation, ns2

```
Check if you are using third-party repositories. If so disable them, since they are a common source of problems.
Furthermore run the following command in a Terminal: apt-get install -f
Transaction failed: The package system is broken
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:

libc6: libc6-dbg: Depends: libc6 (= 2.27-3ubuntu1.3) but 2.27-3ubuntu1 is installed
libc6-dev: Depends: libc6 (= 2.27-3ubuntu1.3) but 2.27-3ubuntu1 is installed
           Depends: libc-dev-bin (= 2.27-3ubuntu1.3) but 2.27-3ubuntu1.3 is installed
libc6-i386: Depends: libc6 (= 2.27-3ubuntu1.3) but 2.27-3ubuntu1 is installed
libc6:i386:
```

After using the comment

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade


The following packages have unmet dependencies
:libc6 : Breaks: libc6:i386 (!= 2.27-3ubuntu1) but 2.27-3ubuntu1.3 is installed 
:libc6:i386 : Breaks: libc6 (!= 2.27-3ubuntu1.3) but 2.27-3ubuntu1 is installed 
:libc6-dbg : Depends: libc6 (= 2.27-3ubuntu1.3) but 2.27-3ubuntu1 is installed 
:libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.27-3ubuntu1.3) but 2.27-3ubuntu1 is installed 
:libc6-i386 : Depends: libc6 (= 2.27-3ubuntu1.3) but 2.27-3ubuntu1 is installed 
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution)
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1296664/edit) it.

Comment: Try use the tips it recommended.

Comment: Replacing the text with screenshot is a very bad idea unless the issue can only be described graphically. I have rolled back your edits. Also, please edit your question and add the output of `lsb_release -a;apt-cache policy libc6`.

Comment: No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Release: 18.04
Codename: bionic
libc6:
  Installed: 2.27-3ubuntu1
  Candidate: 2.27-3ubuntu1.3
  Version table:
     2.27-3ubuntu1.3 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
     2.27-3ubuntu1.2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
 *** 2.27-3ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

Comment: Run `sudo apt update; sudo apr upgrade`. You have packages ready to be upgraded. Once done, retry installing ns2.

Comment: I tried what you said and Last few lines showed something this .......(showing in next comment)

Comment: Fetched 13.1 MB in 15s (849 kB/s)                                                                                                                                    
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
9 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
sudo: apr: command not found

Comment: Should i Run this command "apt list --upgradable"

Comment: I mistyped the second command. Run `sudo apt upgrade`.

Comment: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6 : Breaks: libc6:i386 (!= 2.27-3ubuntu1) but 2.27-3ubuntu1.3 is installed
 libc6:i386 : Breaks: libc6 (!= 2.27-3ubuntu1.3) but 2.27-3ubuntu1 is installed
 libc6-dbg : Depends: libc6 (= 2.27-3ubuntu1.3) but 2.27-3ubuntu1 is installed
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.27-3ubuntu1.3) but 2.27-3ubuntu1 is installed
 libc6-i386 : Depends: libc6 (= 2.27-3ubuntu1.3) but 2.27-3ubuntu1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: Please [edit] your question and append above error message and output of `apt-cache policy libc6:i386`

Comment: libc6:i386:
  Installed: 2.27-3ubuntu1.3
  Candidate: 2.27-3ubuntu1.3
  Version table:
 *** 2.27-3ubuntu1.3 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.27-3ubuntu1.2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main i386 Packages
     2.27-3ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you installed, but ill provide you with complete instruction to download, build and install `ns2`

Step 1: Download `ns2` from the link https://sourceforge.net/projects/nsnam/files/latest/download

Step 2: Make a new directory in `/home/user_name` called `ns2` and copy the downloaded file `ns-allinone-2.35.tar.gz` to this directory.

Step 3: Update package list

```
sudo apt update
```

Step 4: Update some dependencies(packages/libraries)

```
sudo apt install build-essential autoconf automake libxmu-dev
sudo apt install gcc-4.8 g++-4.8
```

Step 5: Now `cd` to this directory `ns2` and extract the downloaded file

```
 tar zxvf ns-allinone-2.35.tar.gz
```

Step 6: Run the install script

```
 sudo ./install
```

Step 7: Open `bashrc` file to set the Environment Variables using

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

Add the following lines in the file. Be sure to change `user_name` with your user name

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/user_name/ns2/ns-allinone-2.35/bin:/home/user_name/ns2/ns-allinone-2.35/tcl8.5.10/unix:/home/user_name/ns2/ns-allinone-2.35/tk8.5.10/unix
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/user_name/ns2/ns-allinone-2.35/otcl-1.14:/home/user_name/ns2/ns-allinone-2.35/lib
```

Step 8: Run the command

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Step 9: Validate the installation. Go to the directory

```
/home/user_name/Documents/ns-allinone-2.35/ns-2.35/
```

and run:

```
./validate
```

After a long while, if you received the “%” sign, it means that ns2 is running.